# How would I run this as an apple executable file?

Tags: bash, macos, execution

so I have this simple executable .command file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Desktop;
python hoi.py;
exit;
```

Whenever I run this, it displays this in the terminal:

> Tom-Diterwich:~ student$ /Users/student/Desktop/run.command ; exit;
>
> /Users/student/Desktop/run.command: line 1:{rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1348cocoasubrtf170: command not found
>
> /Users/student/Desktop/run.command: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
>
> /Users/student/Desktop/run.command: line 2: `{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}'
>
> logout
>
> [Process completed]

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inadvertently saved the file as RTF (Rich Text Format) using **TextEdit**, whereas the `bash` shell just wants plain text rather than documents containing italicised, bold or large font text.

Load the file again in **TextEdit** and press

<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+T

this corresponds to clicking menu items: **Format->Make Plain Text**. Now re-save over the existing file and all will work.

You can readily check whether a file is Rich Text Format (RTF) or plain text using the `file` command like this:

```
file SOMEFILE
```

and you will either get:

```
SOMEFILE: Rich Text Format data, version 1, ANSI, code page 1252
```

or

```
SOMEFILE: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

---

By the way, you can remove all the semi-colons and the `exit` from your code as they are superfluous.

---

Note that you can make `TextEdit` always use plain text for new documents and always save plain text by running these commands in Terminal:

```
# Use plain text mode for new TextEdit documents
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit RichText -int 0
# Open and save files as UTF-8 in TextEdit
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit PlainTextEncoding -int 4
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit PlainTextEncodingForWrite -int 4
```