# Automating import of songs from a list into iTunes?

Tags: applescript, itunes, finder, spotlight, apple-musickit

All my music is kept in a folder on my external HD called 'General Music'.

I have a list of selected songs in a text file called 'SL'. I really want to import them into Music into a playlist called 'SL playlist'!

The list 'SL' is tab-separated and looks like this:

> "Help[TAB]The Beatles[TAB]1965".

It does occasionally contain some special characters (:,å, that kind of thing).
Is it possible to get Applescript to search my computer/hard drive for the string of words listed line-by-line in a text file like this "Help The Beatles 1965", and add any files into Music?

I realise sometimes the file won't find a song for whatever reason but I don't care about errors, I'm happy for it to try and move on if unsuccessful. I also realise there might be more than one music file found but again, I can deal with that. Really appreciate any help as moving from computer to another has left me a bit lost! (Now on Venture 13.5.)

Just to explain why I need this: I made a script to go through the list and copy the text from each line and then I would paste this into Spotlight and copy the file, but with 7000+ you can imagine how slow my progress is! Also, I would import all my files into 'iTunes' (Music now) but I have over 50,000 and I don't want to import them all!

Comment: So if the line in SL is *"HelpTABThe BeatlesTAB1965"* does that mean **all** those 3 **exact** terms must appear in that exact order and nothing else in a file's name for it to be imported?

Comment: Also you should say if all the songs are in a single directory or in a hierarchy. And say what extensions they use.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So no, the order of the words isn't important but if all the words are there it should identify most of my songs. And to your second point — the folder 'General Music' contains folders that contain more folders so it will need to search recursively. Extension-wise, MP3 and m4a only. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in `bash` rather than Applescript so I hope you just want a result rather than worrying about the method. You can run the commands below by typing them into **Terminal**.

So, first thing is to generate a list of all your tracks and save it in your HOME folder as `TRACKS`. I can't see what your disk is called or how things look on your machine but you want something very similar to:

```
find "/Volumes/DRIVENAME/General Music" -type f > $HOME/TRACKS
```

You should be able to check if it is correct with:

```
cat $HOME/TRACKS
```

---

Now you want a script to search for items from SL in there. So you need to save the following as `$HOME/searcher.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\t' read title artist year ; do
   echo Searching for title: $title, artist: $artist, year: $year
   grep -i "$title" TRACKS | grep -i "$artist" | grep "$year"
done < $HOME/SL
```

That assumes your SL file is in your HOME directory.

If you use **TextEdit** to write the script, ensure it is *plain text*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911262/2836621).

Now you need to make that file executable (necessary just once) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/searcher.sh
```

Then you can run it with:

```
$HOME/searcher.sh
```

and see if it identifies the tracks. If that works, we can get those tracks into **Music** as a second step.

---

Second step... don't start on this till first step is looking good. Also, reduce your `SL` file to just 2-3 lines in case it goes wrong so there's not too much to put right!

So, if the above finds your files, we now need to add them to a playlist. So, manually make a playlist yourself, say `"Old Stuff"`, then change the code above so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\t' read title artist year ; do
   echo Searching for title: $title, artist: $artist, year: $year
   this="$(grep -i "$title" TRACKS | grep -i "$artist" | grep "$year" | head -1)"
   osascript -e "tell application \"Music\" to add (\"$this\" as string) to playlist \"Old Stuff\""
done < $HOME/SL
```

Comment: Thanks! All the other steps worked but this one: When I run $HOME/searcher.sh I get this error:

/Users/.../searcher.sh: line 5: /SLtest: No such file or directory~

I've tried changing the reference to SLtest.txt but no luck.

Comment: Start a new **Terminal** and run `cd` to change to your HOME directory. Then type `ls SL*` to see all files whose names start with `SL`. Then edit your script so the last line is `done < THATFILENAME`

Comment: Note I am assuming you have placed the file `SL` in your HOME directory.

Comment: OK, I have done that on a test file and it seems to work - I get the following:
Searching for title: '74-'75, artist: The Connells, year: 1993
Searching for title: '74: No, artist: The Magnetic Fields, year: 2017
Searching for title: '77, Life Ain't All Bad, artist: The Magnetic Fields, year: 2017
/Volumes/EXTERNALHD/Full backup/General Music/02 Rock/02E Rock 2010-2019/08 2017/50 Song Memoir - Magnetic Fields - 2017/'77, Life Ain't All Bad - The Magnetic Fields - 2017.mp3
etc!

Comment: I can't read that in a comment because it's unformatted. Please click `edit` under your question and add it in there properly formatted. Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, after each line *"Searching for..."*, there should follow one line with the full path that corresponds to that track. So it would be good to know what sort of percentage of your tracks it is actually finding. I mean, if there are 30 tracks in SL, there should be 60 lines in the output.

Comment: Hi - thanks, so yes I've used the script on the full file and of 7391 files it has found 5530, so around 75%. That number is not a problem and would be a real help to me as it is even. One thing I've noticed: it doesn't seem to process files with parentheses/brackets in very well. (About 3,000 of the titles it didn't find have () in them somewhere and some of the artists.). I hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, I wasn't expecting special characters in there. Try adding `-F` to the parameters of every `grep` so parentheses and brackets are not treated as metacharacters, e.g. `grep -Fi  "$title" TRACKS | grep -Fi  " $artist" | ...`

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to pick up a few more but the ones it isn't adding I don't get why (I find I can find these if I search on Spotlight and put quotes around the title and artist so they do seem to be visible to Finder etc.:
`Adiós Nonino (Piazzolla) Astor Piazzolla (Rodolfo Nerone) 1955
Aftermyth Of War (from Beyond the Fringe) Beyond The Fringe (Cast) (prod. George Martin) 1961
Ain't Misbehavin' (Waller, Razaf, Brooks) Louis Armstrong & His Orchestra 1929
Alfie (Bacharach, David) Cilla Black (Conducted By Bacharach) 1966`

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this, but suspect it is the quoting on the line starting `osascript`. There may be another way to import songs into **Music** by selecting all the files in a directory rather than using `osascript`, so maybe you could make a temporary directory on your Mac somewhere and replacing the `osascript` line with a `copy` command to copy the song to the temp directory and then import everything from that directory at the end, then delete it. It would be `cp "$this" TEMPDIR` instead of `osascript...`